# How to fit log(a-x) type functions with scipy. curve_fit?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function which looks like `log(y)=a*log(b-x)+c`, where `a`, `b` and `c` are the parameters that need to be fitted. The relevant bit of code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def logfunc(T, a, b, c):
    v=(a*np.log(b-T))+c
    return v

popt, pcov=curve_fit(logfunc, T, np.log(Energy), check_finite=False, bounds=([0.1, 1.8, 0.1], [1.0, 2.6, 1.0]))

plt.plot(T, logfunc(T, *popt))
plt.show
```

Where `T` and `Energy` is some data that was generated (I use it to plot other things so the data should be fine). `T` is between 0.3 and 3.2. I am pretty sure that the problem is the fact that there is a point where `b=T` because I keep getting the error `ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point`. but I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Never just assume the data is fine. Even if it's OK in another place it may lead to problems here. Best create artificial data directly in the example. This makes the problem verifyable for others (And as a plus, working out which particular combination of data causes the problem may lead you to the actual solution).

Comment: Something to look out for: If `T` is between 0.3 and 3.2, what do you think will be the result of `log(b-T)` if `b` is bounded between 1.8 and 2.8? (Also I'm not sure of the initial values are all 1, regardless of the bounds.)

Comment: @kazemakase That's an important point. In any case setting a `p0` is probably a good idea. Moreover, one will run into problems if `min(b) < max(T)`. So one should check this. Finally the question: why not fitting the exponential version, anyway? There one would avoid the `log( negativNumber )` problem.

Comment: @kazemakase Thank you for the input. I am kinda new to posting questions here so I am not too familiar with the etiquette, so I'll keep what you said about data in mind.

Comment: @IlinKaragjozov it's partly etiquette but mostly in your own interest. The easier you make it for others to reproduce and fix your problem the more likely you will get an answer. If one can simply copy, paste, and run the code people are much more likely to look into the problem in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the `lmfit` package (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful for this sort of problem.  This provides a higher-level approach to curve fitting problems and a better abstraction of Parameters and Models than `scipy.optimize` package or `curve_fit()` function.

For the problem here, two important features of `lmfit` are

1. the ability to set bounds on variables.  `curve_fit()` can do this as well, but only by working with ordered lists of min/max bounds.  With `lmfit`, the bounds belong to Parameter objects.
2. having a way to explicitly set a policy for handling NaN values, which could definitely cause problems for your fit.

With lmfit, your script would be written approximately as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def logfunc(T, a, b, c):
    return (a*np.log(b-T))+c

log_model = Model(logfunc, nan_policy='raise')  # raise error on NaNs
params = log_model.make_params(a=0.5, b=2.0, c=0.5) # initial values
params['b'].min = 1.8  # set min/max values
params['b'].max = 2.6 
params['c'].min = 0.1  # and so forth 

result = log_model.fit(np.log(Energy), params, T=T)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(T, Energy, 'bo', label='data')
plt.plot(T, np.exp(result.best_fit), 'r--', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('T')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log', basey=10)
plt.show()
```

This is slightly more verbose than your starting script because it gives a labeled plot and because using Parameter objects instead of scalars gives more flexibility and clarity.

For your fit, you might consider setting the `nan_policy` to 'omit', which will omit NaNs as they occur -- never a great idea, but sometimes helpful to get you started on finding where `log(b-T)` is valid.  You could also alter your model function to do something like

```
def logfunc(T, a, b, c):
    arg = b - T
    arg[np.where(arg < 1.e-16)] = 1.e-16
    return a*np.log(arg) + c
```

To explicitly prevent one obvious cause of NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

> Residuals are not finite in the initial point

means the initial point is bad, where some logarithms are infinite or undefined.  You need a better initial point.

By the nature of the model, `b` has to be greater than any of the points in T. The bounds on `b` that you have at present do not guarantee that. Tighten them up.

When you do not provide `p0` parameter, SciPy will take a guess within the provided bounds. So if the bounds guarantee finiteness, the error will not occur. 
Still, it is generally better to prescribe `p0` yourself, because you have better *a priori* understanding of the problem than SciPy does.

A working example with adjusted bounds:

```
popt, pcov=curve_fit(logfunc, np.linspace(0.3, 3.2, 6), [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3], bounds=([0.1, 3.2, 0.1], [1.0, 3.6, 1.0]))
```