# How to get a log function fit using Scipy curve_fit for the data

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to get a*log(b/x)^c type fit for the following data (simplified for 10 data points)

I have tried methods described in some other questions [like this one using both curve_fit and lmfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265395/how-to-fit-loga-x-type-functions-with-scipy-curve-fit) but the solution never converges. My guess is that my initial conditions are bad. I was able to get the other exponential function commented out fit but the application requires a log fit of the form given. The data with the fit that works is attached for reference.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


x=[0, 0.89790454, 1.79580908, 2.69371362, 3.59161816, 4.48952269, 5.38742723, 6.28533177, 7.18323631, 8.08114085]
y=[0.39599324, 0.10255828, 0.07094521, 0.05500624, 0.04636146, 0.04585985,  0.0398909,  0.03340628, 0.03041699, 0.02498938]
x = np.array(x,dtype=float) 
y = np.array(y,dtype=float)


def func(x, a, b, c):
    #return a*np.exp(-c*(x*b))+d

    return a*(np.log(b/x)**c)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=[.5,.5,1],maxfev=10000)

print(popt)

a,b ,c = np.asarray(popt)
```

[image: Decay function plot with exponential fit for reference]

Comment: What is `a*(np.log(b/x)**c)` supposed to mean for `x=0`?

Comment: Well, good point. a*(np.log(b-x)**c) then? I can't honestly get any log fit to converge

Answer (score 1):

Replace your function with,

```py
def func(x, a, b, c):
    #return a*np.exp(-c*(x*b))+d
    t1 = np.log(b/x)
    t2 = a*t1**c
    print(a,b,c,t1, t2)
    return t;
```

Yow will rapidly see that `t1 = np.log(b / x)` may be negative (this happens whenever b < x). A power of a negative number to a non-integer power is not a real number, and here numpy is producing `nan` results.

Answer (score 0):

I have no difficukty with my fitting software (result below).

Often a cause of difficulty with non-linear fitting using iterative method of regression is the setting of initial values of the parameters to start the iterative process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this might be a very ignorant question, but whats the equivalent function for that in terms of natural log? I am clearly not a math guy and always confuse these. The reason I want a natural log based fit is because thats what the theoretical derivations say while the data I have is experimental.

Comment: And which software is that, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: With notations ln=natural logarithm and Log=logarithm base 10 the relationship is ln(y)=ln(10)*Log(y). Thus the above fitted equation becomes ln(y)=ln(a)-b * x ** c . Or if you prefer     Log(y)=(ln(a)-b * x ** c)/ln(10) = Log(a) - b * x ** c/ln(10).

Comment: Or Log(y) = Log(a) - Log(e) * b * x ** c

Comment: My software is home-made, based on a non-conventional method : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales .